# Different Output for "Every Other" Foreach Statement?

Tags: categories, php

I'm currently using the following code in order to get subcategories in a category page and getting the posts foreach subcategory. In the part where it echos "span-12" (line 14) i want it to echo "span-12 last" for every other subcategory.

my code:

```
<?php  $cats = get_categories('child_of='.get_query_var('cat')); 

foreach ($cats as $cat) :

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1, // max number of post per category
'category__in' => array($cat->term_id)
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    echo '<div id = "seasonBlock" class = "span-12" >';
    echo '</br><h3 class = "seasonTitle" >'.$cat->name.'</h3>';

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>     
    <?php /*general loop output; for instance: */ ?>
    <div id = "episodeBlock" >
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
    aired <?php if(!function_exists('how_long_ago')){the_time('F jS, Y'); } else { echo how_long_ago(get_the_time('U')); } ?><br />  
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php else : 
    echo 'No Posts for '.$cat->name;                
    endif; 
wp_reset_query();

endforeach; ?>
```

In this part, (line 14)

```
 echo '<div id = "seasonBlock" class = "span-12" >';
```

i want to echo for every other category foreach, i want it to echo like this

```
 echo '<div id = "seasonBlock" class = "span-12 last" >';
```

I found some code for adding and checking if it is odd, but that doesn't seem to work for this code.

Comment: This appears to be a **PHP** question, not a **WordPress** question. [Recommended reading](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function to help with this to functionally mimic Ruby on Rails' `cycle` helper:

```
/**
 * Cycle/alternate unlimited values of a given array.
 * 
 * For instance, if you call this function five times with
 * `cycle_it( 'three', 'two', 'one' )`, you will in return get:
 *    three two one three two
 * 
 * This is useful for loops and allows you to cycle classes.
 *
 * Example:
 * 
 *     foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
 *         printf(
 *             '<div class="%s">...</div>',
 *             esc_attr( cycle_it( 'odd', 'even' ) )
 *         );
 *     }
 * 
 * This would alternate between `<div class="odd">...</div>` and
 * `<div class="even">...</div>`.
 * 
 * You can pass any data as args and as many as you want, e.g.
 * 
 *     cycle_it( array( 'foo', 'bar' ), false, 5, 'silly' )
 *
 * @param mixed ...$args Any number of arguments to cycle.
 * @return mixed Alternating value passed through the function arguments.
 */
function cycle_it() {
    static $cycle_curr_index;
    $args = func_get_args();
    $fingerprint = sha1( serialize( $args ) );
    if ( ! is_array( $cycle_curr_index ) ) {
        $cycle_curr_index = array();
    }
    if ( ! is_int( $cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] ) ) {
        $cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] = -1;
    }

    $cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] = ++$cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] % count( $args );
    return $args[ $cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] ];
}
```

If you add it to your theme's functions.php file, you can then change your code to this:

echo `<div id="seasonBlock" class="span-12' . esc_attr( cycle_it( '',' last' ) ) . '" >';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop counter to accomplish this. Set up a counter variable before you loop, check to see if it divided by 2 returns a 0 remainder (in this case) and adjust the class accordingly.  Increment the counter at the end of each loop.

*EDIT: updated code to use the built in counter in the foreach loop as per @goldenapples suggestion.*

```
<?php  
$cats = get_categories('child_of='.get_query_var('cat'));
foreach ($cats as $counter => $cat) :
    $class = ($counter % 2) != 0 ? 'last' : '';
    // snip snip
    echo '<div id="seasonBlock" class="span-12 ' . $class . '" >';
    // snip snip
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: Even easier, just use an implied counter in the `foreach` loop: `foreach ($cats as $counter => $cat) :`
 _(Note: this would start with 0, rather than 1 in your example)_